How can I set Multisampling in gtksharp glarea?
I created a gtksharp project, and use glarea as Opengl renderer. But their is no way to open Multisampling. Anyone can help me...
How to open Multisampling in glarea
The official document doesn't show me how to open Multisampling.
This code is based on default GTK# template.
Basic  Code:
GLArea gLArea = new GLArea();
MainBox.PackEnd(gLArea, true, true, 0);
gLArea.Realized += GLArea_Realized;
gLArea.AutoRender = true;
gLArea.CreateContext += GLArea_CreateContext;
gLArea.Render += OnRender;
gLArea.Realize();

private void GLArea_Realized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var glarea = sender as GLArea;
    glarea.MakeCurrent();
    glarea.HasAlpha= true;
    //glarea.HasDepthBuffer = true;
    glarea.HasStencilBuffer = true;
    glarea.UseEs = false;
    glarea.AutoRender = true;
    isRealized = true;
}

I call a C++ dll from method "OnRender"
[DllImport("GLRender", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DrawMap();

And enable multisample under C++ code.
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
I drew a quard, everything is fine, except anti aliasing。
Code :
https://github.com/JokerX08/GtkSharpGlareaExample
